# API's Exposed by AVICODE

Tags: .net, api, avicode

Does Avicode Expose Any API's which we can use to save the reports  in MHTML format or any other format created by avicode?

Answer (score 1):

AVIcode exception or performance event can be saved manually as MHTML - there is a menu option to download it as MHTML file. I've automated it and created UnBugIt! add-on to allow one-click event sharing via e-mail or TFS.

Reports from Advisor are rendered using MSSQL Reporting Services and you can reuse the automation from there.

What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Can u explain more on what u have done?i have been looking similar to this thing

Comment: i have also automate but my process is creating URL for that event ,opening that URL in background and save it at a particular location....